# Detecting duplicates in a string

Tags: r, duplicates, stringr

Looks like I have another problem dealing with strings in R...

What I am after is quite simple, but I have yet to find a way of doing it, despite many hours of searching on here and elsewhere.

Basically, I have a column in a data table ('Unique ID') that contains a string of words that I want to classify according to whether or not it contains multiple instances of the same word.

An snapshot of my data is:

```
Unique ID
#[1,] Display-imp
#[2,] Display-clk
#[3,] Display-clk Display-imp Display-clk
#[4,] Display-imp Search Affiliate Display-imp
#[5,] Display-imp Display-imp
#[6,] Display-clk Display-clk Display-clk
```

Using the above example data, I would create a new column with a flag in it for those strings that contain only multiple instances of the same word.

Thus rows 1, 2, 5, 6 would all be flagged under this method.

I thought about using str_count function from the stringr package, but this requires me to specify the pattern I want to detect, whereas I am only interested in if any word appears multiple times within a string. And in any case, I don't know what the words are going to be beforehand, so cant specify some sort of list to reference against.

Any help greatly appreciated once again!

Comment: `strsplit`, `unique`, and `length`?

Comment: how do rows 1 and 2 contain multiple instances of the same word and 3 and 4 not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Unique_ID = c("Display-imp", "Display-clk",
                "Display-clk Display-imp Display-clk",
                "Display-imp Search Affiliate Display-imp",
                "Display-imp Display-imp",
                "Display-clk Display-clk Display-clk"))
```

Just use `strsplit`, `unique`, and `length`.

```
counts <- vapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Unique_ID), " "), 
       function(x) length(unique(x)), 1L)
counts
# [1] 1 1 2 3 1 1
```

Use `which` to tell you which rows only have 1 unique value:

```
which(counts == 1)
# [1] 1 2 5 6
```